# How to fix the space delimiter between a columns

Tags: python

I am loading a dat file which is space delimited and reading it through csv to fetch different column data , but while reading the file in second column it takes three different columns for a single name ,as i had used space delimiter How can i read those names in a single column .I want the output as same as input .Thanks in Advance.

```
import pandas as pd
list_of_lists = []
with open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\file.dat', encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        inner_list = [line.strip() for line in line.split()]
        list_of_lists.append(inner_list)
df22=pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)
df22
```

[output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ctvS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first and last elements of the list "inner_list" as the first and third columns respectively and the remaining as your second column.

```
Entry = [inner_list[0], " ".join(inner_list[1:-1]), inner_list[-1]]
list_of_lists.append(Entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

data = []

with open('test.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        line = row[0].split(' ')
        col1 = line[0]
        col2 = ' '.join(line[1:-3]).strip()
        col3 = line[-3]
        col4 = line[-1]

        data.append([col1, col2,col3,col4])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=str)


#Output
                    0                   1               2            3
0  0000000000000000000                ravi  00221111333220   1112123100
1  1121321213435413243  dinesh kumar singh  33332142132121   3322654654
2  2453454435413543544                john  22245346534121  13321425742
3  2323536835353565968        trilok padhi  23353435735410  32135435323
4  2435434321231457400           ravi teja  22221111111110  00153435465
```

Comment: Actually i'm trying to do this in a dat file with around 6500 rows and 300 columns ,how can i do the same with such a large file

Comment: so I guess you have multiple text columns to handle?